# Gridview partial load ASP.NET web page

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview on one of my ASP.NET pages.  One of columns is depending on a result from a web service.  And, that web service call sometime takes long time, so the gridview also takes long time to load.  I would like to know if there is a way I can populate the other columns first, then display them on the gridview while the web service finishes to fetch the data for the column (Like, putting a loading indicator on the column while it finishes).

Thanks.